# Как заполнить многомерный массив в данном случае на Python?

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Выполняю университетские задания, там много задач, где ввод выглядит вот так:

```
Дан массив, в нём, например, пять столбцов и N строк. Посчитайте сумму всех значений. 
a1: 1 2 3 4 5
a2: 6 7 8 9 10
a3: 11 12 13 14 15
 ...
an: 9 5 4 6 4
```

Вопрос в том, как правильно заполнить такой массив с помощью input()? Как должен выглядеть цикл для многомерного массива?

Comment: Так как это учебное задание, вам стоит привести свой код и(или) рассуждения о том, как это делать, а также в чём у вас затруднение.

Comment: Точно так же, как и без `input`.

Comment: Отталкивайтесь от того, что двумерный массив можно представить в виде списка списков: `dbl_arr = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], ..., [9,5,4,6,4] ]`

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Reading file string into an array (In a pythonic way)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052673/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я, кажется, нашёл более-менее верное решение:

```
b = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
```

Таким образом я получил, что хотел. Например, при n = 3 массив выглядит таким образом:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Но мне кажется, что это можно немного проще сделать, пока не знаю, как.

Comment: по [ссылке, которую я привёл](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468957/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python#comment522375_468957) есть совсем простое решение: `a = numpy.loadtxt(sys.stdin)`. Если нельзя другие библиотеки использовать, то `a = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in sys.stdin]` (Python 3) вполне приемлемый код.

Answer (score 0):

Можно также пойти и через словарь! потом проще считать сумму думаю

```
l={}
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(1,n):
        l[i,j] = int(input())
```